# Cassandra: adding back a removed node

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax, opscenter

1. One of the nodes in my cassandra is down and I would like to 'nodetool removenode xxx' it from another node to get going.  If I want to add this node back to the cluster, would it continue with the data that it already has?
2. Suppose I want to remove an entire ring (DC) from the cluster. What would be the right or easy way to do it?  I have all the nodes in a ring down, should I just do 'nodetool removenode' from a node in another ring?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### nodetool remove

Once you run nodetool remove, your cluster stops counting on this node for all its operations. For example, if you have RF2 and had 4 nodes, removing one node will result in streaming the partitions that used to sit on that node across the remaining nodes in your cluster.

If you have a node that has been offline for a significant period of time, it is recommended that you bootstrap a fresh node rather than trying to re-start it and running repair. When data has changed significantly, it is less expensive to stream a fresh set of data than to construct merkel trees and stream missing pieces.

#### Removing a DC

Before removing the nodes in your DC, ensure your client is not pointing to those nodes and modify your replication settings at the keyspace level so as to exclude the old DC.

Once this is done you can run nodetool decomission on each of the nodes in the DC you plan to remove.